# Identify foreign film about a young boy and girl, and an ogre in a forest

Tags: identify-this-movie

On late night Australian television, I once watched a foreign film (possibly French, but I'm not sure). It is a live action colour film, and seemed to be based off a fairytale story. I started part way through, and remember that most scenes incorporated a dark colour palette and atmosphere. There was at least one major scene shot at night time, involving an ogre's mansion/lair in a forest.

The story was about a young boy as the main protagonist, who meets and befriends a little girl. I think from memory she had frizzy curls, and her hair may be blonde. Apparently the girl is the child of an ogre who lives in the forest. Her name was "Rose" (possibly pronounced "Ross" with a rolled "r"). There was a climatic scene where the boy sneaks into the ogre's house and either had to battle or escape from it after stealing something, I don't exactly remember. At some point during this scene, I remember the girl mumbling to the ogre "But I don't want to be(come) an ogress"; of course, this is the subtitle translation of whatever language the film is in.

I also remember that there were a group of boys (possibly brothers of the main character). The ending of the film shows a peaceful scene with golden sunlight. The group of boys were playing around. The girl is there, happy and smiling, though I don't think she was playing with them, maybe just sitting on the side. There is a man's voice-over narration, and it is revealed that the narrator was the young boy protagonist in the story. One of the last lines of this voice-over implies that he and the girl became a couple. It was phrased in a sort of question, maybe something along the lines of "And can you guess who Rose ended up with?".

Some of the details in my mind are a bit hazy, but I saw this film some time between 2000 and 2010. From from what I remember the ogre looked scary, but a bit fake (indicating it wasn't a recent film judging by the possible CGI or even quality of costume).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the French fantasy film [Le petit poucet](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0249081/combined) from 2001.

> Poucet is a kid from a family of numerous children. The parents, too poor to feed them, decide to abandon them in the forest. Their, the brothers try to find their way out making fantastic encounters. This film is based on the French fairy tale "Le petit poucet" by Charles Perrault.

One character is an ogre's daughter called Rose and it ends with the exact scene you've described. The movie was based on [this old fairytale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hop-o'-My-Thumb). Here's the trailer: